# Single Sign On not working on TV

Tags: single-sign-on, samsung-smart-tv

I've created a basic application (virtually no content, just a blank page) to test the SSO functionality. It doesn't work, when I test on the TV it gives the error `error_cp_001`.

The **config.xml** contains, among other things:

```
<cpauthjs>Authorization8888.js</cpauthjs>
<login>y</login>
```

The **Authorization8888.js** file contains:

```
var Authorization8888 = {};
Authorization8888.checkAccount = function(id, pw, cb) {
    cb("TRUE");
};
```

I have already tried with `<cpauthjs>Authorization8888</cpauthjs>`. I have also tried with `Authorization` without 8888 for the filename and vars. It always shows that error.

I also tried in the SDK simulator, same error as on the real TV. On the simulator I see these extra debug lines:

```
[JS ALERT]:  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@22222eval(accountCheckFunc) error
[JS ALERT]:  Fail to load Account check moudule. 
Error : Can't find variable: Authorization8888
```

I can share the zip file containing the whole application, but it's really simple to reproduce since it has nothing except this basic SSO-related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, posting it in case someone else hits the same problem.

The problem was deploying via USB. Apparently, an application deployed with the USB stick has limited functionality. Deploying the application via a web server fixed a lot of issues, including this one.